# Disprove why 0 ∉ Z

Tags: fake-proofs

Disprove this

A value x is said to be an integer when

floor(x) = x, where x ∈ ℝ

floor(x)/x = 1

Therefore

floor(x)/x ∈ Z, where x ∈ ℝ

And since 0 ∈ ℝ

From the definition of an integer,

floor(x)/x ∈ Z, where x ∈ ℝ

if 0 ∈ Z,

floor(0) = 0

Then

floor(0)/0 = 1 ∉ Z

Comment: why am i getting downvotes. im trying to understand this.

Comment: Why do you care about $\lfloor x\rfloor/x\in\mathbb Z$ when $\lfloor x\rfloor/x=1$ is the required property ?

Comment: because you're making the mistake of assuming floor(0) to be 0, but that assumes 0  is an integer. This is really to disprove that floor(0) is actually 0.

Comment: Where are you getting your definition of "integer"? I've *never* seen anyone require integers to satisfy $\lfloor x\rfloor/x=1$.

Comment: Where did you get this definition of integer?

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of "integer" is wrong - we do **not** require $\lfloor x\rfloor/x$ to equal $1$.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct.

Comment: If you add $x=0\lor$, this is not such a wrong definition of an integer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, but then it's a *very different definition* (and in fact just a consequence of "$\lfloor x\rfloor=x$," so it's redundant).

Comment: How is this right? it's simple algebra. floor(x)/x = x/x which is floor(x)/x = 1

Comment: @AjeetKljh $x\over x$ is *not* always $1$ - if $x$ is zero, $x\over x$ is undefined.

Comment: This definition (or property) is useful in the context of this proof, as the proof is all about the ratio $\lfloor x\rfloor/x$. So there is nothing extraterrestrial about it. [Of course well all know that the definition excludes $0$, not counting the fact that the entire proof is wrong.]

Comment: @MorganRodgers The OP does not strike me as a troll, necessarily - they have asked other questions which are definitely not nonsense. I think this falls into the "basic error" category, instead.

Comment: @AjeetKljh What does that have to do with anything? Undefined does not equal $1$, and we never assume that it does - how on earth are you concluding that integers must satisfy $\lfloor x\rfloor/x=1$ (unless you're starting with this as part of the definition of integer, in which case where are you getting this definition)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber what exactly is the definition of "undefined" anyway?

Comment: @AjeetKljh I think if you do not understand the definition of "undefined," you should ask a separate question about that (and your specific confusions) - I don't think the comments are a good place to hash this out. Briefly, though, **not** every mathematical expression is automatically assumed to be meaningful - think of "$x\over y$" as shorthand for "the unique number which, when multiplied by $y$, gives $x$." Such a number may not exist, or may not be unique, in which case that expression is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There are two big flaws:

- $\frac00$ is not defined and there's nothing you can conclude about it.
- there is no justification of your final $\notin$. On the opposite, $1\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think the OP was actually using the fact $0\over 0$ is undefined to derive ${0\over 0}\not\in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $1\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ and hence a contradiction. The only real problem in this proof, is, as stated in other comments, the definition of integer is wrong. If the floor definition were the right definition of integer, then it would actually be a valid proof by contradiction.

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor=x$ is strictly equivalent to $x=0\lor\lfloor x\rfloor/x=1$, so there's nothing wrong with the alternative definition (in this fixed version; such a definition being "unfamiliar" isn't a valid argument to refute it). The real issue in the proof is the meaning of $0/0\notin\mathbb Z \land0/0=1\implies 1\notin\mathbb Z$ (?!)

Comment: Indeed, if you fix the definition then there is no problem at all. The problem in OP's proof is he uses the definition "If $x$ is an integer then $\lfloor x \rfloor \over x$$=1$"